# Listview selected item background color not changing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, listview

I have this list view that contains list of hotels as link button. When I am selecting a hotel name from listview, I would like to change its background color so that it look like it is selected. I have tried many options but nothing worked.

```
<asp:ListView ID="HotelListView" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <p class="listviewMargin selectedHotelCss">
       <asp:LinkButton ID="SelectedHotelLinkButton" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullName")%>' selectedHotel='<%# Eval("Id")%>' CommandName='selectedHotel' CssClass='darkOliveText'>
       </asp:LinkButton>
     </p>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

try 1 using CSS:

```
p.selectedHotelCss a.selected { background-color:red;}
```

try 2 using JQuery:

```
$('[Id$=<%= SelectedHospitalLinkButton.ClientID %>]').on("click", function () {

    $(this).addClass('selectedText');
});
```

try 3 using SelectedItemTemplate:

```
  <SelectedItemTemplate>
    <tr class="selectedText">
      <td>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="SelectedHospitalLinkButton" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullName")%>' selectedHospitalId='<%# Eval("Id")%>' CommandName='selectedHospitalId' CssClass='darkOliveText'>
         </asp:LinkButton>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </SelectedItemTemplate>
```

What is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Did you check the CSS class "selectedText" on another control? can you please check that you are not refilling the list view on each postback

Comment: "selectedText" is working on Treeview for selected node. No, List view is not refilling on post back

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code on document ready:

```
 $('#<%=SelectedHospitalLinkButton.ClientID%>').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selectedText');
 });
```

Comment: yes, alert is coming. Your Jquery function is getting called. In Mine case also it is getting called. I believe it could be a problem of PostBack